# How come specific questions get much more exposure than others?

Tags: discussion

I notices that most questions on the economics site get very few views,
One large anomaly, is this question:
[Car prices haven't changed in 20 years, no inflation?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/24948/car-prices-havent-changed-in-20-years-no-inflation/24953#24953)

I can only assume that this question was promoted somehow in search engines, social networks, different stack exchange sites

The thing is, that not only was the number of view higher, but the number of votes casted on the question and answers. Economics users flocked to that question, unlike others

What's the secret ? can it be recreated with other questions, making the econpmics stack exchange site much more active ?

Comment: I don't have access to traffic stats enough to know where some questions get all their views from. My partial guess is that a lot of questions that aren't HW and super academic, simple enough for laypeople to understand, those are the questions that get the most attention (but it is not guarantee it will get a lot of attention).